# MFC maximize window feature

Tags: c++, mfc, fullscreen

I have tried to make the fullscreen feature of a SDI application with splitter windows by following the forum [link](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=363365). However, my status bar, system menu as well as the title bar of the application have disappeared. Do you have any suggestions on any easy ways of getting these back (or if I have to use different method of making the application maximized during startup instead of fullscreen)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got rid of any manipulations on the cs structure in the PreCreateWindow handler and used a ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE) function call in the OnCreate function implementation of my MainFrame function, and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want the window to be maximized. Take a look at the [SetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633544%28VS.85%29.aspx) function or [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx).